# How to link to the kth link on another web page in simple html?

Tags: html, hyperlink

My goal is to have a link on my web-page that always seamlessly redirects you to the top link on the front page of reddit.com when you click it. So you would presumably be able to click the link on my page and it would maybe search the html of reddit's front page, find the link at the very top, and automatically redirect you to that. Any ideas on how to do this? It's kind of weird-- like a link to a link...

Comment: Impossible with "simple html"

Comment: If they have any anchors you could utilize them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with pure HTML. You will need either Javascript or server-side code, in which you retrieve the source of Reddit's homepage, parse it to pick out the link you want, and use its `href` attribute's value as the `href` value for your own link.